# How can I calculate values in a Pandas dataframe based on another column in the same dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, moving-average

I am attempting to create a new column of values in a Pandas dataframe that are calculated from another column in the same dataframe:

```
df['ema_ideal'] = df['Adj Close'].ewm(span=df['ideal_moving_average'], min_periods=0, ignore_na=True).mean
```

However, I am receiving the error:

```
ValueError: The truth of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any(), or a.all().
```

If I have the `span` set to 30, or some integer, I do not receive this error. Also, `ideal_moving_average` is a column of float.

My two questions are:

Why exactly am I receiving the error?

How can I incorporate the column values from `ideal_moving_average` into the `df['ema_ideal']` column (subquestion as I am new to Pandas - is this column a Series within the dataframe?)

Thanks for the help!

EDIT: Example showing Adj Close data, in bad formatting

```
Date              Open        High         Low       Close   Adj Close                                                                           
2017-01-03  225.039993  225.830002  223.880005  225.240005  222.073914   
2017-01-04  225.619995  226.750000  225.610001  226.580002  223.395081   
2017-01-05  226.270004  226.580002  225.479996  226.399994  223.217606   
2017-01-06  226.529999  227.750000  225.899994  227.210007  224.016220   
2017-01-09  226.910004  227.070007  226.419998  226.460007  223.276779   
2017-01-10  226.479996  227.449997  226.009995  226.460007  223.276779
```

Comment: Do you have example data? It looks like you're passing a Series as the first argument in the `DataFrame.evm` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering, the problem was that `span` could not take multiple values, which was happening when I tried to pass `df['ideal_moving_average']` into it. Instead, I used the below code, which seemed to go line by line passing the value for that row into `span`.

```
df['30ema'] = df['Adj Close'].ewm(span=df.iloc[-1]['ideal_ma'], min_periods=0, ignore_na=True).mean()
```

EDIT: I will accept this as correct for now, until someone shows that it doesn't work or can create something better, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this will work for you:

```
df['ema_ideal'] = df.apply(lambda x: df['Adj Close'].ewm(span=x['ideal_moving_average'], min_periods=0, ignore_na=True).mean(), axis=1)
```

Providing `axis=1` to `DataFrame.apply` allows you to access the data row wise like you need.

Comment: What exactly do `axis=1` and `lambda` do? Also, I'm unsure if this command works correctly, the moving average is waay lower than another ewm created with `span=30`. Also, when I do `df['ema_ideal']` it returns with  many rows of `<bound method EWM.mean of EWM [com=7.623898,min_periods=0,adjust=True, ignore_na=True,axis=0` where the number is different every time, but I would need it to just be float/integer

Comment: See the updated answer, `Mean` was missing parens so it was returning the method itself and not the value that `Mean` computes. As for `lambda` and `axis=1`, you can read more about it here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#row-or-column-wise-function-application

Comment: hmm, that doesn't seem to work either, receiving this error: `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 207, placement implies 1`, FYI `df['ideal_moving_average']` has 207 rows

Comment: Well `ewm` doesn't resolve to a single value so you're not going to just be able to squeeze `207^2` values in one column. You have to do something else to get a single value, but I'm not sure what your requirements want from it.

Comment: It's not that I'm trying to squeeze `207^2` values, really I want to iterate through each row, adding that value of that row to the `span` attribute

Answer (score 0):

There's absolutely no issue creating a dataframe column from another dataframe.

The error you're receiving is completely different, this error is returned when you try to compare Series with logical fonctions such as `and`, `or`, `not` etc...

In general, to avoid this error you must compare Series element wise, using for example `&` instead of `and`, or `~` instead of `not`, or using numpy to do element wise comparation.

Here, the issue is that you're trying to use a Serie as the span of your ema, and pandas ewma function only accept integers as spans.

You could for example, calculate the ema for each possible periods, and then regroup them in a Serie that you set as the `ema ideal`column of your dataframe.